# Titanium Mobile and Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

Can you use the google map API directional services in Titanium? And if not what can I use instead of it?

Answer (score 0):

i have only been able to pass a link and have the browser open with directions. See this thread for further discussion

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/1161/link-to-native-google-maps